# Bootstrap trigger Dropdown inside a div give an error

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I using React JS, and I wanted to trigger a dropdown and the dropdown was inside a div className="row". If I put the data-toggle and data-target inside the div like this :

```html
             <div className="row">
                  <div
                    className="col-lg-6"
                    id="dropdownMenuButton"
                    data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                      <div className="times">
                        <span className="dot" />
                        <span className="dot" />
                        <span className="dot" />
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

and it gives this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
```

But, if I put the data-toggle inside the className="row", it works but that's not what I wanted because the trigger length would be long as the "row" width.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `col-2` div inside the row and put the toggle button there. Use [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/bars) icons to create three bars icon inside the button.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```